# Doubt regarding spring force on strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

[image: 1]

Here, it has been said that the tension $T$ acting on the string is $3mg$ due to the masses $2m$ and $m$. But there is also a spring connected. Why don't we take that into account while finding $T$?

Comment: Springs are often considered massless to simplify these types of problems. If the spring is considered to have mass then string tension would be 3m+spring mass.

Answer (score 1):

You can.

The small mass $m$ is at rest. The small mass experiences gravity, and upward tension from the spring, in balance, so $mg = S$, where $S$ is the tension of the spring.

The large mass $2m$ is at rest. The large mass experiences gravity and downward tension from the spring, balanced with upward tension from the string, so

$$2mg + S = T$$

$S = mg$, so $T = 3mg$. This *does* take into account the spring.

You can either choose:

- to think of the two masses separately, considering the effect of the small mass on the string through the spring,

or

- you can choose to think of the two masses combined, ignoring the
  spring.

You cannot add $mg$ from the small mass *and* $mg$ from the spring at
the same time, as that would be double-counting. Both are different ways of looking at the effect of the small mass.

Comment: If the lower block moves in SHM, the tension in the string changes right?

Answer (score 0):

The tension $T$ isn't so useful in this case, because it suddenly changes when the spring breaks (suddenly becoming $T_+=0$).  The force exerted by the spring, however, is useful.  It isn't suddenly changed by the spring breaking -- the force exerted by a spring is proportional to how much it is stretched/compressed, and nothing more.  That stretching doesn't change when the string breaks.

Accordingly, you can solve this in two steps:

- First, find the force that the spring must exert in order to keep the second mass up in the steady state solution.  This is, of course, $F_{spring}=mg$
- Second, find the acceleration of the first mass after the spring has snapped.  After the spring has snapped $T=0$, but $F_{spring}$ is still present, and still equal to $mg$ because the spring hasn't had the opportunity to shrink.  Thus, the forces on the first block are gravity, $(2m)g$ and the spring force, $mg$, both in the downward direction.  These, of course, sum to $3mg$.

  - This is not necessarily attributable to the $T=3mg$ tension force on the wire, although it happens to line up in this case.  It is entirely due to gravity and the spring force.  This particular problem happens to have an answer that is the same as the answer to "what is the tension force in the string," but in general, focus on the forces that exist after the sudden change to the system.